# Styling dialog boxes in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, styling

I've been trying to set a basic (not at all custom) dialog box using a fragment, and having difficulties. As you can see in the attached in image, the background shadow isn't correct and the title has white at the left and right hand side.

[image: Fragment as a dialog]

Following advice from [How to style AlertDialogs like a pro](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/) I tried setting the alert dialog style through my app, and copying the style out of the Android SDK but this doesn't seem to make much difference.

```
<!-- Local copy of android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.Alert -->
<style name="Theme_Holo_Dialog_Alert" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_full_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>

<!-- Local copy of android:DialogWindowTitle.Holo -->
<style name="DialogWindowTitle_Holo">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>
```

and I tried setting the style directly using

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_Alert);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
```

and also

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

None of which make a difference to the background shadow or the title styling.

Any ideas?

**Update 1:** The layout of the dialog is set using a fragment and added to the builder as a view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
_layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_cycles, null);
builder.setView(_layoutView);
```

using the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editStageCyclesSpin" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update 2:** Removed the padding and changed the height/width in response to Alok Nair

I removed the padding and changed the layout width and height but unfortunately this had no effect on the white space in the title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editStageCyclesSpin" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using a custom view alert dialog?

Comment: I use a layout stored in a fragment and set in the builder. 

`LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
_layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_stage_step, null);
builder.setView(_layoutView);`

Comment: Can u post code of that layout?

Comment: Remove those paddings. And set height and width to match_parent. Regarding background shadow, do you want shadow or no shadow?

Comment: I want a shadow. As the image shows, there's currently a light background behind the dialog box.